# Converting a variable amount of arguments into an explicit amount

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to implement a resource manager that manages specific loaders and provides a load() function which redirects to the individual load() functions of the loaders. The manager also does some kind of garbage collection for example by calling a *freeUnusedResources()* method of each loader to unload unused resources.

**Problem:**
The conversion of a variable amount of arguments into an explicit amount.
I want each loader implementation to be able to provide different load functions with a fixed amount of arguments while the interface/base class *IResourceLoader* can handle a variable amount, which is needed for the single *load()* function of the *ResourceManager*.

So something like:

```
class IResource;   //Resources hold only data
class AResource : public IResource {};
class IResourceLoader {     //Loader load resources
    virtual IResource* load(...);
    //or
    template<typename ...Args>
    IResource* load(Args ...args);

    virtual void freeUnusedResources() = 0;
};

class ALoader : public IResourceLoader {
    std::vector<IResource*> _loadedResources;

    IResource* load(std::string path);  //"Implementing" IResourceLoader::load(...)
    IResource* load(std::string path, int a, int b); //"Implementing" IResourceLoader::load(...)
    void freeUnusedResources() override;
};

class ResourceManager {
    //A map of the resource type a loader can load
    std::map<std::type_index, IResourceLoader*> _loaders;

    template<typename ResourceClass, typename ...LoaderArgs>
    IResource* load(LoaderArgs ...args) {
        IResourceLoader* loader = _loaders.find(typeid(ResourceClass))->second; 
        return loader->load(args...);
    }

    void update() {
        for(auto &l: _loaders) {
            l.second->freeUnusedResources();
        }}
};
```

Now to load a resource, you would simply need:

```
ResourceManager rm;
//Add some loaders to the manager, then load
rm.load<AResource>("path/to/resource", 10, 20);
```

The whole point of this is to ensure that no resource is loaded more than once and that there are no multiple instances of a loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the user is giving you the type, you can perform a cast, and do not need to make it virtual any more:

```
class IResourceLoader {
    virtual void freeUnusedResources() = 0;
    virtual ~IResourceLoader() = default;
};
```

Next, we need to have a type map from resources to loaders, so that when the user asks for a resource, we know which loader to use.

```
template <class Resource>
struct ResourceToLoaderType;

class ALoader : public IResourceLoader {
    std::vector<IResource*> _loadedResources;

    ResourceA load(std::string path);
    ResourceA load(std::string path, int a, int b);
    void freeUnusedResources() override;
};
template <>
struct ResourceToLoaderType<ResourceA>{
    using type = ALoader;
};
```

And then, finally:

```
template<typename Resource, typename ...LoaderArgs>
Resource load(LoaderArgs ...args) {
    auto& resource = *_loaders.at(typeid(Resource));
    auto& loader = dynamic_cast<
         typename ResourceToLoaderType<Resource>::type &>(resource);
    return loader.load(args...);
}
```

I do a dynamic cast on a reference so that it throws if your map has gotten messed up. But if you do the insertions correctly then that dynamic_cast will always succeed. Now, each `Resource` can define its `load` function however it wants; the user of the manager is responsible for making sure the arguments are consistent with the loader. The nice thing is that if they pass arguments inconsistent with the `load` signature, you get a compile time failure, not run time. Indeed, you should never get a run-time failure if you keep the map consistent.

Couple of other nitpicks:

- use `unique_ptr`, the manager should own the resources
- use perfect forwarding

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake: the `template<typename Resource, ...>` should be `template<typename ResourceClass, ...>`.  I don't quite understand the `auto& resource = *_loaders.get()`: shouldn't resource now be of type `IResourceLoader` ?
Another thing: Are you sure a  `std::map::get(T key)` exisits? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Gordon Sorry, should be `at`, not `get`.  I also got rid of explicit typeindex constructor because not necessary. Yes, `resource` is of type `IResourceLoader`, and then you downcast. The downcast is dynamic so in theory it can fail at runtime, but your map is indexed by the dynamic type, so the downcast should always succeed. Once you downcast you can the methods of `ResourceClass`, and `load` need not be virtual nor have a consistent signature between different resources.

Comment: I hope I wasn't unclear about this: _IResourceLoader_ is not a base class of `ResourceClass`, there's no inheritance between the two and it's not a resource but a loader for that.  The resources only hold the data and do not define any `load` functions. Therefore the downcast `dynamic_cast<ResourceClass&>(resource)` where `resource` is of type _IResourceLoader_  should not work.
I think you mean `auto& loader = *_loaders.at(...);` and you accidently switched the meaning of `auto& resource` and  `auto& loader`

Comment: @Gordon Yeah, it was unclear in the original edit. I will fix it up again, this design seems sketchy though tbh; overuse of inheritance.

Comment: "_Because the user is giving you the type, you can perform a **cast**, and do not need to make it **virtual** any more_" was the answer for me: When I change the template of `IResourceManager::load(...)` to also take the type of loader and remove the _load()_ function from the _IResourceLoader_ interface, then I can cast the _IResourceLoader_ from the map to that type and call _load()_.
Also, I didn't know that you could store the type of a class with `using type = ALoader;`. 
Thanks for the effort!